# SQLITE multiple row values into columns

Tags: sqlite, case

I have event status table, the table structure is already defined, I would like to make several row value into one row.

current table data:

eventable:

```
EVENT       EVENTNAME       EVENTACTION     STATUS      TIMESTAMP
"Event1"    "FootBall"      "FootBall0"     "started"   "1554980085"
"Event1"    "TableTennis"   "TT0"           "started"   "1554980086"
"Event1"    "FootBall"      "FootBall0"     "success"   "1554980087"
"Event1"    "Chess"         "CHESS0"        "success"   "1554980095"
"Event1"    "TableTennis"   "TT0"           "running"   "1554980189"
"Event1"    "FootBall"      "FootBall1"     "started"   "1554980082"
```

I need to select query to display the data as follows:

```
EVENT       EVENTNAME       EVENTACTION     STATUS      STARTTIME   RUNNINGTIME ENDTIME
"Event1"    "FootBall"      "FootBall0"     "success"   1554980085  NULL        1554980087
"Event1"    "TableTennis"   "TT0"           "running"   1554980086  1554980189  NULL 
"Event1"    "Chess"         "CHESS0"        "success"   1554980098  NULL        1554980100
```

I have to show the `EVENT`, `EVENTNAME`, `EVENTACTION` and latest `STATUS` and timestamp of `started`, `running` and `success`, If the time is not there then should set `NULL`.

I have used SELECT query with case but the timestamps doesn't place in single the relevant row.

```
SELECT AE.EVENT,
AE.EVENTNAME,
AE.EVENTACTION,
AE.STATUS,
(case WHEN AE.STATUS='started' THEN AE.timestamp END) as starttime,
(case WHEN AE.STATUS='running' THEN AE.timestamp END) as runningtime,
(case WHEN AE.STATUS in ('success','failed') THEN AE.timestamp END) as endtime
FROM agentEvents AE 
ORDER by timestamp ASC
```

Any leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate by event, and then take the `MAX` of the `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    AE.EVENT,
    AE.EVENTNAME,
    AE.EVENTACTION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AE.STATUS = 'started' THEN AE.timestamp END) AS starttime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AE.STATUS = 'running' THEN AE.timestamp END) AS runningtime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AE.STATUS IN ('success', 'failed') THEN AE.timestamp END) AS endtime
FROM agentEvents AE
GROUP BY
    AE.EVENT,
    AE.EVENTNAME,
    AE.EVENTACTION
ORDER BY
    MAX(CASE WHEN AE.STATUS = 'started' THEN AE.timestamp END);
```

Note that it makes no sense to order by the `timestamp` column alone, because it no longer exists after aggregation.  So, I order by the starting time instead.  It also makes no sense to select the `STATUS` column, so I have removed it.

Comment: @1863229 `EVENTNAME` repeats with different timestamp it takes the latest record, how do we change the query if I wanted to show history too.